# How to count lines of CSV file before parsing. using CSVHelper and .net-core

Tags: c#, .net-core, csvhelper

I would like to make sure I'm not starting to parse a monstrous CSV file before starting to parse it and set a limit to protect my code. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: You could always just check the `FileInfo` of the file beforehand

Comment: Please show your code. There is no way anyone can help answer your questions without an understanding of what you've done to "make sure".

Comment: Do you want to read the file twice?  You can only get line count by reading the file unless each line has the same number of bytes.